# Nested loop in razor view ungroups my radiobuttons

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, model-binding

I'm having some difficulty rendering my form properly. In my view, a product has several `Properties`, and each property has several `Options` that can be selected, either using checkboxes if multiple selections are allowed, or radio buttons if not.

This razor-code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Type.Properties.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <strong>@Model.Type.Properties[i].Label</strong><br />
        @if (Model.Type.Properties[i].AllowMultipleSelections)
        { // Multiple selections are allowed - we need checkboxes:
            @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Type.Properties[i].Options.Count(); j++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Id)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].Selected)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].Selected,
                    Model.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].StringValue)
                <br />
            }
        }
        else
        { // Multiple selections are NOT allowed - we need radio buttons:
            @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Type.Properties[i].Options.Count(); j++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Id)
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].SelectedId,
                    Model.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].Id)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].Selected,
                    Model.Type.Properties[i].Options[j].StringValue)
                <br />
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

... will render this HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <strong>Size</strong>
    <br />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Id" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Options_0__SelectedId" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Options[0].SelectedId" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label for="Type_Properties_0__Options_0__Selected">20-24</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Id" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Options_1__SelectedId" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Options[1].SelectedId" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label for="Type_Properties_0__Options_1__Selected">25-29</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Id" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="Type_Properties_0__Options_2__SelectedId" 
            name="Type.Properties[0].Options[2].SelectedId" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label for="Type_Properties_0__Options_2__Selected">30-34</label>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <strong>Suitable for</strong>
    <br />
    <input id="Type_Properties_3__Id" 
            name="Type.Properties[3].Id" type="hidden" value="1002" />
    <input id="Type_Properties_3__Options_0__Selected" 
            name="Type.Properties[3].Options[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <label for="Type_Properties_3__Options_0__Selected">Women</label>
    <br />
    <input id="Type_Properties_3__Id" 
            name="Type.Properties[3].Id" type="hidden" value="1002" />
    <input id="Type_Properties_3__Options_1__Selected" 
            name="Type.Properties[3].Options[1].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <label for="Type_Properties_3__Options_1__Selected">Men</label>
    <br />
</div>
```

The problem is that the `id` and `name` for the radiobuttons will get unique values (`id="Type_Properties_{i}__Options_{j}__SelectedId" name="Type.Properties[{i}].Options[{j}].SelectedId"`), and thereby "ungrouping" them. This, of course, means that I am able to select all the radio buttons in a group, when I just want to be able to select one. How can I fix this?

Update:

My models:

```
public class ViewModelProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewModelProductProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string LongInfo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductType Type { get; set; }

    public List<ViewModelPropertyForProduct> PropertiesForProduct { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelPropertyForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }

    public ViewModelProduct Product { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductProperty Property { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelPropertyOptionForProduct> SelectedPropertyOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelPropertyOptionForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyOptionId { get; set; }

    public ViewModelProduct Product { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductPropertyOption PropertyOption { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProductPropertyOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; } // Is this the selected option for that property? For checkbox
    public int SelectedId { get; set; } // The Id of the selected option for that property. For radiobutton

    public string StringValue { get; set; } // (Option - a string ("Green"))
    public ViewModelProductProperty Property { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ViewModelPropertyOptionForProduct> SelectedOptionsForProperties { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProductProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } // ("Color")
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool AllowMultipleSelections { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool AssignedToProductType { get; set; }

    public List<ViewModelProductPropertyOption> Options { get; set; }//("Red")
}
```

Comment: You need to show your models (which need to be corrected so that they contain a property to bind the selected option to). But even if you fix that, your `@if (Model.Type.Properties[i].AllowMultipleSelections)` block means that you will be generating non-zero based, non-consecutive indexers which will not bind anyway so you need to make further modifications to the model and/or view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the models.

Comment: Your models are a bit of a mess for what your are trying to do. And you also have not shown the `ViewModelProductType`. Its also hard to understand what the `ViewModelPropertyOptionForProduct` and `ViewModelProductPropertyOption` models are for (or what the difference between them is.

Comment: Best guess is that your have a `Product` which has properties (for example `Color`) and you want to generate either radio buttons to select a `Color` (or checkboxes in the case where a property could have multiple selections). Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, you are right about the products' properties. Which properties are for which products are set in `ProductType`, which has a range of properties for that type of product. `ViewModelPropertyOptionForProduct` is which option has been selected for a certain product. `ViewModelProductPropertyOption` is all available options for certain properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added `ViewModelProductType` to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168075/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-stian).

Comment: If y'all figured this out "in chat", I'm sure there are people who would be VERY interested in the fix. Like, ME for instance. I have almost the exact same issue and I cannot figure out how to get my radio buttons to group right in the inner-most of two for loops.